# How can I read the current headers without making a new request with C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, http, header

Since JS cannot get the initial page request, can C# get the current headers without making a new request?

The main goal is to be able to determine who is accessing the page by looking at the HTTP header that has a custom value "uid": "world" that is passed in. After determining it, the value is then displayed on that same page.

```
Hello "world"
```

Can this be done in C#? How?

Comment: Is This ASP.NET? Do you want to get a particular header on the server side and then display them?

Comment: Yes, it is ASP .NET... I have a .cshtml file. It is more like the user will pass in a particular header to the page so that I can display it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access the headers within your MVC controller, you can use this:

**Controller**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var uid = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["uid"];

    // Add your view model logic here...
    var model = new TestModel
    {
        HeaderValue = uid
    };

    return View(model);
}
```

**View**

```
@model MyProject.Models.TestModel

<div>
    Hello @Model.HeaderValue
</div>
```

Comment: var uid = HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["uid"]; //"Current" is an unresolved symbol. Is there a library I'm missing? I have "using System.Web.Mvc;"

Answer (score 2):

In ASP.NET, you can read the [Headers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.headers(v=vs.110).aspx) from the [Request](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest(v=vs.110).aspx) object. My answer is assuming Web Forms, please update your question if you're not using Web Forms (it's important to include that information in your initial question in the future).

```
<asp:Label runat="server" id="HeaderLbl" />
```

And code behind:

```
using System.Web; //add this to the top of your class if it's not already there

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    HeaderLbl.Text = Request.Headers["uid"];
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In your controller, use `System.Mvc.Web.Mvc.Request.Headers` to get the headers from the current request.

If you are using Razor, you can include `@Request.Headers` directly on your .cshtml page and share the contents with Javascript, if you want.